# Python Standard Library not installed?

Tags: python, standard-library

I'm fairly new to Python and recently started development on a new mac mini. As you know it comes with 2.7 installed.

The problem I'm running across is the Standard Library doesn't seem to be installed.

I get a syntax error when importing modules (SyntaxError: invalid syntax).

I was running this code with the argv datafile.csv

```
import csv
import sys

stocks.csv = argv
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')

try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
finally:
    f.close()
```

After awhile of this I decided to run the interpreter and get help.

When I ran the interpreter and do help(csv) or most other modules (sys works just fine) I get this error:

```
>>> import csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "csv.py", line 1
    import 
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do I need to install the library or am I accessing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a new file in a different directory; put just 'import csv' in it. Run it. Odds are there is something wrong with your original program file. Simplest may be to just retype it perhaps...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have a file in the current directory named `csv.py` with a blank `import` statement on line 1? Python searches the current directory for imports before it looks at system directories.

Answer (score 1):

importing module that can not be found causing

```
ImportError: No module named {...}
```

error `SyntaxError` means that text in file "csv.py" isn't valid python code.

Maybe you have your own "csv.py" somewhere that is shadowing original csv lib?